# CMake test doesn't show up in test explorer on gcc build

Tags: cmake, visual-studio-2019, ctest

Currently looking into testing for windows and linux with cmake. I've made a small project that I want to build and test on both. Building works for me. And I've added a dependency to boost test to add a very simple test.

**For windows**, this test shows up in the test explorer of visual studio and I can run the test fine from there or use the command line.
**For Linux**, I can run the testproject from the commandline, but my test don't show up in the Test Explorer.

### Question

Is adding boost test for a linux build to the Test Explorer not possible at the moment with visual studio? Or is there something wrong with my approach?

I'll include the CMake of the testproject below. If you'd like to see the whole project pls visit https://github.com/gertkommer/BoostTestCmakeExample

Using `Visual Studio 2019 pro 16.5.3`

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.16)

find_package( Boost 1.70.0 REQUIRED COMPONENTS system filesystem unit_test_framework)
project(MyProject_test)

add_executable (${PROJECT_NAME} 
    "BoostTest_test.cpp" 
)
add_definitions(-DBOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK)

#set(BOOST_LIBRARIES Boost::unit_test_framework Boost::system Boost::filesystem)
if (WIN32)
    if (CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE MATCHES "Debug")
        set(BOOST_LIBRARIES ${Boost_LIBRARY_DIR_DEBUG}/boost_unit_test_framework-vc140-mt-gd.lib
        ${Boost_LIBRARY_DIR_DEBUG}/boost_system-vc140-mt-gd.lib
        ${Boost_LIBRARY_DIR_DEBUG}/boost_filesystem-vc140-mt-gd.lib
            )
    endif()
endif()
if(UNIX)
    set(BOOST_LIB_DIR ${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS}/libboost_unit_test_framework.so)
    if (CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE MATCHES "Debug")
        set(BOOST_LIBRARIES ${Boost_LIBRARY_DIR_DEBUG}/libboost_unit_test_framework.so
        ${Boost_LIBRARY_DIR_DEBUG}/libboost_system.so
        ${Boost_LIBRARY_DIR_DEBUG}/libboost_filesystem.so
            )
    endif()
endif()

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME}
    PUBLIC ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR}
)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
    ${BOOST_LIBRARIES}
    MyProject
)

add_test(MyBoostModule ${PROJECT_NAME})
```